# Network settings are lost after server reboots

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have installed debian on my old computer and assigned a static IP address to it through `/etc/network/interfaces`.

However when I boot my server the settings in the interfaces file are lost.

Only when I restart networking interfaces using `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, the settings are loaded. They don't load automatically on server boot up. What's the problem?

My interfaces file is like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.42
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: paste your /etc/network/interfaces file content

Comment: sanksr, you need to register on the site to be able to regain control of your question. Also, we don't use BB Code here for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using something other than `networking` to manage your networking, such as `NetworkManager`, which uses different configuration files. You have two good choices. You can fully switch over to [NetworkManager](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager) and configure things there. Or you can switch over to `networking` by disabling the `NetworkManager` service and making sure `networking` is set to run on startup.

Answer (score 0):

the interfaces file seems correct, if networking restart solves the problem it might not autostart on the appropriate runlevels check if links ./rc6.d/S35networking and ./rc0.d/S35networking do exist. Also check in /var/log/messages and dmesg for clues what can prevent to bring the interface up.